# Enum with constructor in switch-statement

Tags: java, enums

It might be a silly question, but I can't understand why it doesn't work:

```
public class MainClass {

    public enum Header{
        ValueType("Value Type"),
        LimitType("Limit Type"),
        Currency("Currency");

        Header(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        private final String value;

        public String getValue(){
            return value;
        }
    }

    static void getHeaderValue (String headerValue) {

        switch (headerValue) {
            case Header.LimitType.getValue() :
                System.out.println(Header.LimitType.getValue());
                break;
            case Header.ValueType.getValue() :
                System.out.println(Header.ValueType.getValue());
                break;
            case Header.Currency.getValue() :
                System.out.println(Header.Currency.getValue());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler notices that

> constant string expression required.

What's the reason for this error message?

Comment: THe constructor here should really be private.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing to do with your *enum* but with your *switch* statement, which needs constants in its **case** clauses. **case** needs constant expressions like `"helloWorld"`, the expression `Header.LimitType.getValue()` maybe returns a value that never changes, but it is not a constant expression to the compiler.

Comment: Thank you! So, if I need to use hardcoded Strings in switch/case an enum is not the case? Are there only one way out is to use final String fields for this purpose?

Comment: @aime if `getValue()` is something that will never change, you could use the enum itself instead of the string, like `case Header.LimitType:`, `case Header.ValueType:`, etc

Comment: I got that. Thank you!